# C# Nullable: How to build a FormUrlEncodedContent from Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a `Dictionary<string,string>` of parameters and want to create a `FormUrlEncodedContent`. See the following sample code:

```cs
var message = new Dictionary<string,string> {{"example", "example"}};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(message);
```

This code works fine with nullable disabled, but enabling it leads to a warning (and since we have WarningsAsErrors enabled, the build fails).

```
Argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' cannot
be used for parameter 'nameValueCollection' of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string?,string?>>'
in 'System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent.FormUrlEncodedContent'
due to differences in the nullability of reference types.
```

I have worked around this by doing `message.Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<string?, string?>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value))`, but this is very verbose, gross, and probably slower.

Any suggestions? Am I missing an obvious way to cast this, or is the `FormUrlEncodedContent` class wrong for accepting a `KeyValuePair<string?, string?>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I know of for current C# is to use `!`: [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+BiAdgVwBtCJhC4ACOXU8gWAChGABABguYEYAWAbhfZcAdADk4MIQAkYMAA78mDAG4QEFMHChQIAc0oBeCrjgB3CgBEAlgGMYlgPY0EATwA8XVkg8A+CgG8/ACI4AA8IMFlyQKQKYLCIqIBfRIUVNWtHeFwYCkNjMwAxewQwAFUEQgBRXAyUOBQAYUzqGAAKDS1dOABCAEpeIA==)

```cs
#nullable enable

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;

var message = new Dictionary<string,string> {{"example", "example"}};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(message!);
```

The problem here is that structs and class type parameters are [invariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance). Because of this, we don't allow implicitly converting `KeyValuePair<string, string>` to `KeyValuePair<string?, string?>`, for example, even though there isn't a real safety issue in doing so.

A solution for a similar problem has been [proposed](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3950) for `Task<T>`. Perhaps the language should introduce a solution that works in both the `Task` and `KeyValuePair` scenario, and perhaps can be extended to other scenarios.

Edit: This issue also revealed a bug in the compiler where certain disallowed nested nullability conversions don't produce warnings. To avoid depending on this bug, I changed the recommended solution. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/53189

Answer (score 3):

The [`!` (null-forgiving) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) does the trick:

```cs
var message = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "example", "example" } };
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(message!);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have found a way around it using `as`:

```cs
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
                message.AsEnumerable() as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string?,string?>>);
```